# How to manually create public domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

So if I would like to create a website called `example.com` ( just an example ). I have name the nameservers `ns1.mynameserver.com` and `ns2.mynameserver.com`, which have A records for `example.com`. How would I add nameservers to my domain, and how would I make this domain public? I have a MacBook (for hosting server), and 2 linux computers for nameservers (both ubuntu)

Comment: by the way, I dont want to have to use an external site to register a domain. I want to create this completely manually.

Comment: You have no idea what you are talking about... Read up on the fundamentals about how DNS operates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the domain name with a domain registrar. Then they can point the the domain to your DNS servers what you can edit as you like later.

Comment: there has to be a way without using a registrar.

Comment: There is.  Any device accessing your website just needs to point their DNS  to your nameservers.  For personal or internal projects this may be acceptable.  For general use, you would find it difficult to get the entire world to point to your DNS ;-)

Comment: You cant do this without a registrar, only if you became one!

Comment: If there was a way without a registrar then people could steal domains for their own use. A registrar is responsible for a given TLD (e.g. .com, .co.uk) and holds the name server records for that domain, along with who is responsible for it. They charge a fee for this service. If you want the world to see it, you must use a registrar, if it's private then just update your local name servers and point the clients at those name servers.